# How to restrict IAM user, can't be create any resources with out tagging "Owner" as "User Name"

Tags: amazon-web-services

Could you please give any solution on this below issue.

> If the resource is not tagged like "Owner" as "User Name", then it will get terminated automatically ".

For the IAM user, how to restrict user so that he can not create any resources without tagging "Owner" as "User Name"?

Is there any IAM policy for this or how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot require tags when creating resources in AWS. You cannot automatically delete resources via AWS for resources that are not tagged unless you write your own code. There is no monitor and cleanup type of task in AWS.

You can however automatically tag resources with who created them (this does not support every AWS resource) using Lambda. I use this solution in all AWS accounts that I manage.

Basically you use CloudWatch events to trigger Lambda on, for example, a new EC2 instance event. The Lambda function then tags the EC2 instance with the owners name. You can modify for anything that you need. This also means that CloudTrail needs to be enabled for the account.

[How to Automatically Tag Amazon EC2 Resources in Response to API Events](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/)

Amazon's solution is very cool and works well.